# Spring request mapping not working when specified in interface

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I write request mapping at interface but it's not working.

Request / response body POJOs:

```java
public class ReqAa {
    private String firstValue;
    private String secondValue;

    public String getFirstValue() {
        return firstValue;
    }

    public ReqAa setFirstValue(String firstValue) {
        this.firstValue = firstValue;
        return this;
    }

    public String getSecondValue() {
        return secondValue;
    }

    public ReqAa setSecondValue(String secondValue) {
        this.secondValue = secondValue;
        return this;
    }
}

public class RespAa{
    private String status;

    RespAa(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public RespAa setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Interfaces:

```java
public interface A{
    interface Aa{
        @PostMapping("/do/something")
        RespAa doSomething(@RequestBody ReqAa);
    }

    interface Ab{
        @PostMapping("/do/another")
        RespAb doAnother(@RequestBody ReqAb);
    }

}

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public interface IClient extends A.Aa{
}
```

Rest Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class Client implements IClient{
    @Override
    public RespAa doSomething(ReqAa reqAa) {
        return new RespAa("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Spring boot `@RequestBody` could not mapping as Body. Its took it as parameter.

Example:

generated request: `/api/admin/do/something?firstValue=fv&secondValue=sv`

expected mapping: `/api/admin/do/something`

requestBody: `{ "firstValue":"fv","secondValue":"sv"}`

its work when i used @RequestBody in implementaion method.

```
@RestController
public class Client implements IClient{
    @Override
    public RespAa doSomething(@RequestBody ReqAa reqAa) {
        return new RespAa("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

I used spring boot version: `1.5.10`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question to improve the readability. Maybe you could include more information related to the "symptoms" that you have? I.e. are you getting a 404?

Comment: i get 200. but wrong request mapping. i want post request with body but its mapped with parameter instead of body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using interface default method.
Working code here:

Interfaces:

```java
public interface A{
    interface Aa{

        RespAa doSomething(ReqAa);

        @PostMapping("/do/something")
        default RespAa dDoSomething(@RequestBody ReqAa){
            return doSomething(ReqAa);
        }

    }

    interface Ab{
        @PostMapping("/do/another")
        RespAb doAnother(@RequestBody ReqAb);
    }

}

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public interface IClient extends A.Aa{
}
```

Rest Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class Client implements IClient{
    @Override
    public RespAa doSomething(ReqAa reqAa) {
        return new RespAa("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```